# Spring mvc - send xml text string to controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. I need to send **an xml string** to my controller, and get this xml as a **simple text string** inside controller. But can not find any solution yet. I tried this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(String post, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   System.out.println("post: " + post);
}
```

and I have `contentType: 'text/xml'` in my ajax config. But the variable `post` always printed as `null`.

Also I tried `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE` and `consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE` in my method, but returns me **`HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type`**. What is the problem? **How can I send simple xml text to my controller?**

Comment: Have you tried request.getParameter("post");

Answer (score 0):

You can read your string using RequestParam:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String test(
    @RequestParam(value="post") String post, Model model){

      ...
 }
```

Comment: The posted xml has not name, so `@RequestParam` will not work. However, I tested your solution and got `400 - bad request: Required String parameter 'post' is not present` error.

Comment: How do you pass it to your controller?